# Android native method not found. Tried many ways

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 0.6.1

My src tree includes:

```
  └── src
│       └── main
│           ├── AndroidManifest.xml
│           ├── java
│           │   ├── android_serial_api
│           │   │   ├── SerialPortFinder.java
│           │   │   └── SerialPort.java
│           │   └── com
│           │       └── elmit
│           │           └── bellusball
│           │               └── app
│           │                   ├── Application.java
│           │                   ├── ConsoleActivity.java
│           │                   ├── LoopbackActivity.java
│           │                   ├── MainMenu.java
│           │                   ├── NOTUSED
│           │                   │   └── MainActivity.java
│           │                   ├── Sending01010101Activity.java
│           │                   ├── SerialPortActivity.java
│           │                   └── SerialPortPreferences.java
│           ├── jniLibs
│           │   ├── armeabi
│           │   │   └── libserial_port.so
│           │   ├── armeabi-v7a
│           │   │   └── libserial_port.so
│           │   └── x86
│           │       └── libserial_port.so
│           └── res
│               ├── drawable
```

I get no error during Sync Project with Gradle files.
I get no error during build.

However, when I run the app on my tablet, logcat reports:

```
06-25 18:48:28.816      400-400/com.elmit.bellusball.app D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.elmit.bellusball.app-2/libserial_port.so 0x411c9d98
06-25 18:48:28.817      400-400/com.elmit.bellusball.app D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.elmit.bellusball.app-2/libserial_port.so 0x411c9d98
06-25 18:48:28.817      400-400/com.elmit.bellusball.app D/dalvikvm﹕ No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.elmit.bellusball.app-2/libserial_port.so 0x411c9d98, skipping init
06-25 18:48:28.817      400-400/com.elmit.bellusball.app W/dalvikvm﹕ No implementation found for native Landroid_serial_api/SerialPort;.open:(Ljava/lang/String;II)Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;
06-25 18:48:28.819      400-400/com.elmit.bellusball.app D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-25 18:48:28.819      400-400/com.elmit.bellusball.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f169a8)
06-25 18:48:28.823      400-400/com.elmit.bellusball.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: android_serial_api.SerialPort.open:(Ljava/lang/String;II)Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;
            at android_serial_api.SerialPort.open(Native Method)
            at android_serial_api.SerialPort.<init>(SerialPort.java:61)
```

The native libserial_port.so is within jniLibs!

build.gradle includes:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native-libs", include: 'native-libs.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    provided fileTree(dir: 'jniLibs', include: ['*.so'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}

task nativeLibsToJar(type: Jar, description: 'create a jar archive of the native libs') {
    destinationDir file("$buildDir/native-libs")
    baseName 'native-libs'
    from fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '**/*.so')
    into 'lib/'
}

tasks.withType(Compile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(nativeLibsToJar)
```

Where do I start and how to fix that?

Comment: Could you fix this problem?

Comment: I have the same error with the same library. Are you sure the .so files are in the APK (use winzip or winrar to check, there should be a lib directory). Second, the loadlibrary command assumes the "lib"  prefix which should be ommitted. So if your lib name is libdoessomething.so you should call System.loadLibrary("doessomething"); I also removed the underscore from the android serialport api library name.